# Why does this Exredis client not throw an error in on_exit callback?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this code in my test

```
setup do
  client = Exredis.start

  on_exit fn ->
    client |> Exredis.query ["FLUSHALL"]
  end

  {:ok, client: client}
end
```

When I run mix test, I will never get an error saying the process of client does not exist on the anonymous function's closure. The test will continue to run and my tests will fail thinking that it clears my Redis.

On the other hand, if you ever try to run Exredis.query on an unexisting process, you'll get an Exit error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_exit/1` callbacks run on a separate process than the test process. That's theoretically why the query should work, if it doesn't, then you would need to investigate `exredis`.

Some advice:

1. If you have many tests that need a connection, I would start a named connection inside test_helper.exs and use it in my tests:

   ```
   Exredis.start(name: MyApp.Redis)
   ```

   Not sure if `Exredis` supports the syntax above
2. I would recommend you to use [redix](https://github.com/whatyouhide/redix) which has a more idiomatic Elixir API. For example, in Elixir's convention, `start` should always return `{:ok, pid}`. But, even though, the library should not promote the use of the `start` function like exredis does, because it means you can leave dangling Redis connections. You should really use `start_link`
3. Remember to not mark the tests that rely on Redis as `async: true`, as you would have race conditions between them